# Android Studio Keyboard Shortcut for full screen mode

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, android-fullscreen, android-ide

I want to enter full screen mode in `Android Studio`. Is there any `Keyboard Shortcut` for doing it. What Is the `Keyboard Shortcut` key for enter and `exit` full screen mode in `Android Studio`?

Comment: i am looking for a keyboard shortcut

Comment: You can make your own. Look https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html

Comment: You can define on File > Settings > Keymap. Look at the gif in my answer.

Answer (score 41):

**In Android Studio** -> MenuBar -> View -> Enter Full Screen

Though there are other options as well which you might like such as Presentation Mode and Distraction free mode

For maximizing the editor pane <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>F12</kbd>  will work on windows.

You Should also check this [**reference**](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)

Full screen is [not mapped](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/intellij-idea-viewing-modes.html) to any shortcuts by default. but you can define your own shortcuts. Please check this [***document***](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html).

*Hope this will help.*

Comment: In the Mac version (2.2.3) it IS mapped by default to control + command + F  to enter/exit full screen mode.

Answer (score 33):

Only for Windows: it's not shortcut but kind of it :) 
To Enter/Exit Full screen mode

```
1. Alt + V (will access Menu -> View) 
2. Arrow Up ^
3. Enter
```

**UPDATE:** Looks like the same keys work on Ubuntu too :)

Comment: And linux too!! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 14):

It's easy. Press ctrl+alt+s or open File > Settings > Keymap and open Keymaps select box the default one. Below the select box, type full screen in the search box and right click on the result to set your shortcut. That's it.
[image: Demonstration of how the process is done]

Answer (score 2):

On Mac and Android Studio 2.3.3 try this :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>

Comment: this full screens the entire project window. how about just the current tab?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with a keyboard macro which combines *Hide All Tool Windows* with *Toggle Full Screen mode*.

First you need to assign keyboard short cuts to both these under `Settings -> Keymap` (*Toggle Full Screen mode* does not have one, but *Hide All Tool Windows* is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>  on my version of `Android Studio`).

Then record a macro under `_Edit -> Macros -> Start Macro Recording_`. Name it as something then assign a `keymap` to it under `_Settings -> Keymap_`.

Now with just one shortcut you can maximize your code area :)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the name "Hide All Tool Windows". I wanted to change it to ctrl+M

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>  (will access Menu -> View) =>  <kbd>Arrow Up</kbd> => <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Example :** Alt + V (will access Menu -> View)  --> Arrow Up ^ --> Press Enter key

Answer (score 0):

Kind of offtopic: In Openbox ToggleFullscreen works for every single
application, so for Android Studio as well.

Just add:

`<keybind key="W-f">`
`<action name="ToggleFullscreen"/>`
`</keybind>`

to your

> ~/.config/openbox/rc.xml

Where `W` is Windows/Mac button on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I found out best way for me was to go to `Keymap` <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> and make a little `control area` to keyboard for me:

- Hide All Tool Windows <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>
- Toggle Full Screen mode <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>
- Toggle Distraction Free mode <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>